# Ubuntu 16 installation on a PC with UEFI Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I haven't been able to install ubuntu 16 on a PC with windows 10 already installed in UEFI mode. The installation reaches the step with the Ubuntu screen and the five dots. After the five dots become red, the screen starts to switch to black to normal, again and again and after some second I can hear the error sound. At this point I can only reboot the machine.

I tried with the grub option *noacpi* and *nomodeset*. With the latter, the only thing that changes is that the screen gets stuck on black.

I look for a solution in the other answers but I didn't found anything that  allowed me to install ubuntu.

Comment: Can you run a live USB session ok?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware incompatibility of some sort. What type of computer is it? (What make and model computer or motherboard? How new is it? Do you have any plug-in cards, especially video cards, and if so, what make and model are they?)

Comment: @OrganicMarble No, I face the problem with live USB session and also trying the installation

Comment: @RodSmith Here's my PC hardware configuration. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1tXuLUsHjSEaEs5ZnNQNTlCc1VJczYwT2NtNVJkTDZJUXBv/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem: on the GRUB screen after selecting the live boot option (same thing works with the installation option), press 'e' in order to insert the GRUB option.

On the next screen, you need to change the GFXMODE option from `keep` to `text`.

Then press F10. 
After this change, the ubuntu installation starts normally.

Here's more information: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/gfxpayload.html