# I'm trying to install on a fresh hard drive and I just get stuck on the loading screen

Tags: usb-installation

https://sirfalmingoiii.tumblr.com/post/190293198471
It's be on this screen since it booted up about 15 minutes ago. The little dots move for a few seconds and then stop.  I'm not getting any options to select language,  my keyboard layout, or anything else.  Any ideas?

Comment: A common problem, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/924119/ubuntu-16-installation-on-a-pc-with-uefi-windows-10  or search this site for "installation dots"

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to use a flash drive that was bottlenecking the data that was passing through it. I pulled out my external hard drive and now it's installing with no problem.